# What is the name of this song from the Funimation Dub of DBZ?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, theme-song, funimation

The song is played often when Frieza is doing evil things. I found a compilation that contains it [at the given time code here.](https://youtu.be/S5pS-hydJms?t=14m36s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That song is the **SoundTrack 7** of DragonBall Z.

You can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_R_qGTBbeZk).

And for more of the DragonBall Z soundtrack album [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFC7776F0C2183335) you have a full playlist with all of them.